# AJAX Load PHP Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I load data from my PHP response via ajax into a panel?

My PHP outputs correctly and I can see a table in the response, but I can;t get it to build the data on my webpage.

Here is my jquery/ajax so far. It passed the value to PHP correctly and PHP builds the table via its echo, but what am I missing for AJAX to display the table?

PHP:

```
<?php
foreach ($lines as $value) {
   echo "<input name='data[]' value='$value'><br/>";
} 
?>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
            $('#rotator').change(function (e) {
                var rotator = $("#rotator").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "tmp/JFM/National/national.php",
                    data: {
                        rotator: rotator
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                         $('#panel').load(result);
                    }
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Your PHP code above is part of national.php? Also, when you place console.log(result); above $('#panel').load(result); What is displayed in console?

Comment: Correct. There is a little more in the script but not pertinent to this, as far as how it grabs data to build the table. That's all working.

Comment: Let me check on that for your ?

Comment: Try .html instead of .load

Comment: Try what @mkaatman mentioned. Use .html instead of .load.

Comment: @cosmoonot console.log displays what I expect it to display. <input name='data[]' value='101.WAV
'><br/><input name='data[]' value='101.WAV
'><br/><input name='data[]' value='102.WAV
'><br/><input name='data[]' value='102.WAV

Comment: Replace $('#panel').load(result); with $('#panel').html(result);

Comment: Ah - I got it. I created a test div and it put it into there with .html(result). It must not be able to append it into my main panel div, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

move your function from:

```
$.ajax({...,success: function(){...}});
```

to

```
$.ajax({..}).done(function(){...});
```

if it doesn't work, try to add async:false into the ajax object...

```
$.ajax({...,async:false}).done(function(){...});
```

Hope it helps... =}

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was two fold.

I was attempting to append to my main div, which apparently can't happen. I created a new empty div and was able to load the results there.

Beyond that, the comments to change .load(results) to .html(results) were needed.

The correct jquery code is below.

```
$(function () {
            $('#rotator').change(function (e) {
                var rotator = $("#rotator").val();
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                    url: "tmp/JFM/National/national.php",
                    data: {
                        rotator: rotator
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                         $('#test').html(result);
                    }
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
```